# making post requests by curl

Tags: php, curl, web

hi i wrote this script to get the html of a website but i see "Invalid Request" Error, but when i create a html form and submit it i have no problem, whats the problem? here is my php code :

```
<?php
$url = 'http://convert2mp3.net/en/index.php?p=convert';
$fields = array(
                        'url' => urlencode("www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntSBKPkk4m4"),
                        'format' => urlencode("3gp")
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string="";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `CURLOPT_POST` should be a boolean, not the int you're setting it as.

Try this, if `$fields` can be dynamic, or just set it to boolean `true`:

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields) > 0);`

Also, why are you building the POST fields yourself? Just pass the whole array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

```
$fields = array(
      'url' => "www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntSBKPkk4m4",
      'format' => "3gp"
);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont success with your missions because they relate source ip address to the key of the conversation that they provide, so after you will get the direct download link in their cdn, your client's won't be able to download it because the related ip address is your web server's ip.